# How to toggle the custom slider horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to toggle the slider horizontally. Currently I have achieved the slider with vertical scrolling. I need to make it to scroll horizontally?

This is what I tried:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#list li:lt(8)').show();

   $('#next').click(function() {
    $('#prev').show();
    var last = $('#list').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll('#list li:lt(8)').toggle(200);
    last.next().prevAll('#list li').hide(200);

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($('#list li').last().is(':visible')){
         $this.hide();
    }
    });

  $('#prev').click(function() {
    $('#next').show();
    var first = $('#list').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll('#list li:lt(8)').toggle(200);
    first.prev().nextAll('#list li').hide(200)

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($('#list li').first().is(':visible')){
         $this.hide();
    }
    });

});
```

Fiddle Example:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tono0da1/3/)

Comment: i can't get the problem, your code is working fine as your expectation you just need to remove max-height from #list

Comment: Its working fine now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works as you describe, but only if you change one of the styles:

```
#list{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

You are limiting the height of the list, meaning that it can't show eight items at once. Increasing the height allows it room to show more.

Comment: Currently I am toggling vertically, how do i can toggle horizontally with same code.?